# Context-free languages and free/bound variables

Tags: context-free

Fix a first-order language $L_0$, and let
$$L=\{f(\varphi)\mid \varphi \text{ is a well-formed formula of $L_0$}\},$$
where $f(\varphi)$ is *$\varphi$ with all occurrences of free variables underlined*.

For example, $L$ contains
$\forall x\forall y(x=y)$ and
$\forall y(\underline{x}=y)$,
but not $\forall x\forall y(\underline{x}=y)$.

> What is known (or can you prove) about $L$ being (not) context-free, or context-sensitive?

Assume that the infinitely many variable symbols are encoded in unary in the form $v(1), v(11), v(111),\dots$ and there are only finitely many non-logical symbols in $L_0$.

Comment: The language is easily seen to be computable in uniform $\mathrm{TC^0\subseteq L\subseteq NSPACE}[O(n)]=\mathrm{CSL}$.

Comment: Can’t you prove it’s not context-free just by applying the pumping lemma to $\forall v(1^n)\,(v(1^n)=v(1^n))$ for large enough $n$?

Comment: Is there a bounded number of variables? Or are they encoded (e.g. in binary)? In the first case it seems easy to derive a CFL by having a NT for each subset of variables representing the free variables, in the second case it seems you cannot have a CFL covering everything because a NT cannot "remember" which  variables are free… (this can be elaborated in a more detailed proof).

Comment: @Louis See the last paragraph.

Comment: Ah sorry. Then I agree with you about pumping. To extend you argument, take the formula ∀x,x=x, with x that has a big enough encoding, then pump in the middle of the last occurrence of x and you get ∀x, x=y with y marked as bound but it is not.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek how do you get TC0? Threshold circuits useful for this?

Comment: Basically, the most complicated thing you need in order to parse a formula is to be able to count brackets. This allows you to check that it is correctly bracketed, and to determine the ancestors of a given symbol in the parse tree, which in turn allows you to decide whether a given variable occurence is free or bound.